# Creating a custom Listview and error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a custom listview

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (view == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_weather_detail, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
        Data data = citiesData.get(i);
        viewHolder.cityName.setText(data.getCity().getName());
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    return view;
}
```

It's breaking when I am trying to access id in city name viewHolder.cityname.

```
class ViewHolder{
    TextView cityName;
    //TextView temperature;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom listView u must do like this:

```
 @Override @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View vi = view;

        if (view == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TextView cityName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
        Data data = citiesData.get(i);
        cityName.setText(data.getCity().getName());


        return vi;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a surprise you get a NPE on the line :

> viewHolder.cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_name);

because 2 lines above that, you are testing that view **is** null.

You are missing the creation of the view:

> view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, parent, false);

Answer (score 0):

you forgot what to do if view is not null

add the following code.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_weather_detail, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
    else

    {viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

            Data data = citiesData.get(i);
            viewHolder.cityName.setText(data.getCity().getName());
        return view;
    }
```

Feel free to ask in case of any query.